# Can I colour my Chart Area background in Mutiple Colours bands - SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Can I colour my Chart Area background in Mutiple Colours bands

That is based on Y - vertical Axis Is it possible to have mutiple bands Ex:In scale of 1 to 100 on Y Axis , Is it possible to have  - 0 -30 Green, 30-70 Blue and 70 -100 Red bands of three different colours

Two colours is possible as background by Alternating Colours, Like this is it possible with 3 or more colours.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can alternate colors using the rownumber expression for rows.

```
=iif(columnnumber(nothing) mod 2, "Green", "blue")
```

For columns it is a little more tricky.  It would be far easier to bind the colors explicitly using a column value you KNOW will be a certain value.

```
IIF( (ColumnName) = (predicate), "Red", 
  IIF( (ColumnName) = (predicate2), "Green", "Blue"))
```

To do either of these just go to the property of a row, column or cell and go to background.  Hit drop down, select 'Expression' and put in the code.

EDIT: 
Working example below will work for TABLE object only NOT a matrix.  Matrix can have dynamically changing values so you need a bit more code to account for that.

Alternates three colors on a table:

```
=iif(rownumber(nothing) mod 3=1, "Green", 
    iif(rownumber(nothing) mod 3=0, "Blue", "Gray"))
```

Comment: I am looking for Chart Background (Bar Graph) and not for Table or Matrix

Answer (score 0):

Different background color bands on SSRS charts are achieved through the **StripLines** functionality.

Have a look at the great answer in following related question: [Conditional background color in line charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842297/conditional-background-color-in-line-charts)