# Conditional background color in line charts

Tags: reporting-services, background, charts, line, zone

I am currently trying to convert our charts over from PQ Systems Chartrunner to SSRS 2008 charts. I am currently working with a line chart in SSRS 2008 and am trying to get the background color to change for the different sigmas. I am able to calculate and chart the standard deviation sigma lines, but I have not been able to change the color of the background between the lines.

What I have so far in SSRS:

[image: SSRS chart]

In the Chartrunner chart, the Red/Yellow/Green zones:

[image: Chartrunner chart]

Is there a way to do this in SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to look at using **Strip Lines** in your report:

[Highlight data by adding Strip Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281363%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

This is a decent link, too:

[Axis Strip Lines in SSRS](http://blog.jontav.com/post/7067899413/axis-striplines-in-ssrs-charts).

Because you can make these expression based, the bands can be determined at run time. It should work in your case as you always have a set number of bands, just different values when you run the report.

Here's a simple example, based off the following dataset:

[image]

Most important thing to note is that I've included the limit rows *max*, *mid*, and *min* in the dataset; these makes the **Strip Lines** easier to create.

Create a simple chart:

[image]

Select the Y **Chart Axis** and expand the **StripLines** collection:

[image]

You can see that I've set **IntervalOffset** and **StripWidth**, based on the fields in my dataset. End result:

[image]

So you can see it's possible to do this dynamically as required. It's a simplified example but the concept is readily transferable; you should be able to adapt it to your requirements.

Comment: Awesome!  I was unaware of this feature and probably would not have found it with the search terms I was using.http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f39/sethmo38/SSRSLineChart2_zpsa581220c.jpg

Comment: Looks great! It actually took me ages to find the name of these today, and I knew the specific functionality actually existed... Just not commonly used, I guess. If this worked for you, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks!