# Coloring values in a chart with the same color

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2, and I have a line chart with several values (12). Some values were changed to Smooth Area.

I need some values to be the same color, but SSRS automatically changes the colors for each series and group

Here an image of the chart as I currently have it built: 
[image: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/31/c1e5.jpg]

My desired output would have the same color for the pink/red areas at the top and bottom of the chart, and the same color for the orange area near the top and the gold area near the bottom, etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842297/conditional-background-color-in-line-charts

Comment: thanks for your response..... i forgot to mention i tried using striplines.... and the example you posted not apply in my case

Comment: Based on the image you posted, it appears that custom striplines should work.  What did the striplines do when you tried them?