# How to insert background color for section Reporting Services

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I would like to create a chart like this with Reporting Services:

[image]

I have insert a simple line chart and it works but now, I want to insert background color, from 0 to 5% blue for background color, from 5 to 10% another color etc...

Now I can fixed it?

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842297/conditional-background-color-in-line-charts

Comment: I have see this so I would like to insert more "stripLine". For this I have create a "StriptLine1", I have set background color ="Blue", IntervalOffset, I have insert the value of Y axis and in StriptWith property I have insert number 5. So I would like insert a new StriptLine and set background color from 5 to 10 value. How can I do it?